# Android : Security Concern :classes.dex Publically exposed WebService Name is visible in the file

Tags: android, web-services, security, apk

I am not too sure about how secure a apk file is and therefore this question.

We have a application which gets the result from a publicly exposed webservice. However, when we tried to open the `classes.dex` file (opening `.apk` with winrar), the webservice name and the soap action were visible in it. This can be a potential issue if someone can get a hold of the apk file and could easily access the exposed webservice url.

It looks like:

```
handleMessage handler hasError hello ht _http:MY WEBSERIVCE NAME
uhttp:MY SOAP Action Name
```

What would be correct approach to get details from a publicly exposed URL? If we write a wrapper around the web service to get the only specific details we want than also this would be visible in `classes.dex`.

Is there a way to protect the `.apk` file from opening from a computer or PC.
Or is there a way to encrypt the webservice name in the program.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the security risk of exposing the URL of your service? Everything reachable on the Internet is _reachable on the Internet_, and you should not make the assumption that keeping the _name_ of your service secret makes you safer in any way. What specific threat are you attempting to mitigate by keeping the name secret?

Comment: Hi sarnold,the webservice URL and soap action can/might retrieve confidential information, moreover anyone could write their app and access this url and customize it.How to avoid duplication of app once we publish to umarket.So we want that only the app published by us should be in a position to access this URL.

Comment: Aha; you should not be performing authentication based solely on the URL -- you should also have per-user user names and passwords or use [client certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate#Client_certificates) to authenticate the individual users. You should consider your application [easy to copy and duplicate](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2011/03/03/droid-dream-android-market-malware-attack-aftermath/), so building the authentication into the application directly will never keep your confidential information private.

Comment: I agree 100% with @sarnold, you need better security on the service itself. Even it you can prevent someone from seeing the URL/etc. in the APK file, they could still be sniffing packets on their local network when connected over WiFi, which makes any attempt to hide the URL pointless if someone really wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't. If you are depending on the fact that your webservice URL is hidden as you security measure, then you are **doing security wrong**.

This URL **will** be discovered, even if the code is encrypted / obfuscated, users can use a debugger to connect to a running application, or simply use a proxy / [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to inspect the web traffic. This is *not* a way to secure your application.

You should have **per-user** login names and passwords or use [client certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate#Client_certificates) to authenticate the individual users. You should consider your application [easy to copy and duplicate](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2011/03/03/droid-dream-android-market-malware-attack-aftermath/), so building the authentication into the application directly will *never* keep your confidential information private.